# Magento - Quickly grab a count of a collection for all products

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to find a quick way to obtain the SKU count from our system (in an external script). I thought the following code would work, but it's loading all of the properties from the collection it seems, and will take quite a while since we have over 600,000 SKUs.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default'); // Default or your store view name.

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$count = count($products);
```

Is there a way to load this in a more efficient way for our purposes.. perhaps just load the SKU instead of all attributes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works -- thank you!

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getsize();
var_dump($products);
```